# how to increment hex value in oracle

Tags: oracle, hex, increment

Im trying to increment one column in oracle table which id defined as raw :

```
ID    VALUE
----------
1    A14
2    B13 
3    C15
4    D16
```

and I need to have

```
   ID    VALUE
----------
1    A24
2    B23 
3    C25
4    D26
```

Is there any function in oracle how to increment ? 
Thanks

Comment: `A14` doesnot seem to be a hex number. Do you simply wanted to increase the numric part

Comment: @XING `A14` is a hexadecimal number `A=10` so it is `10*16^2 + 1*16^1 + 4*16^4 = 2580`

Comment: @MT0 Thanks for your explaination but `select rawtohex(2580) from dual` doesnot give me back `A14`.

Comment: @XING `SELECT TO_NUMBER( 'A14', 'XXX' ), TO_CHAR( 2580, 'XXX' ) FROM   DUAL;`

Comment: @MT0 Can you please explain why `rawtohex(2580) from dual` doesnot give me back `A14.`

Comment: @XING - it converts the bytes Oracle uses to store the value to hex so `DUMP( 2580 )` gives `Typ=2 Len=3: 194,26,81` so the underlying bytes are `194`, `26` and `81` and then `TO_CHAR( 194, 'FMXX' ) || TO_CHAR( 26, 'FMXX' ) || TO_CHAR( 81, 'FMXX' )` is `C21A51` which is what `RAWTOHEX( 2580 )` gives.

Comment: @MT0 Thanks for explaination.

Answer (score 2):

Use `TO_NUMBER` and `TO_CHAR` with the format mask `X` for a hexadecimal digit:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59e770/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME (
  ID    INTEGER,
  VALUE VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME
SELECT 1, 'A14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'C15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'D16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'FFF' FROM DUAL;

UPDATE table_name
SET value = TO_CHAR( TO_NUMBER( value, 'XXXX' ) + TO_NUMBER( '10', 'XX' ), 'FMXXXX' );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59e770/2/0)**:

```
| ID | VALUE |
|----|-------|
|  1 |   A24 |
|  2 |   B23 |
|  3 |   C25 |
|  4 |   D26 |
|  5 |  100F |
```